# Can ejabberd be installed on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, google-compute-engine

Can ejabberd be installed on Google Compute Engine?  Will there be any issues with using ejabberd on Compute Engine?  I have looked but cannot find any references to anyone trying this before.  Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Compute Engine gives you VMs. You can put whatever you want on them, such as Erlang and ejabberd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

You can use the Vm with Debian Image and follow this intructions.

http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-mail-jabber-server-xmpp-with-iredmail-and-ejabberd-on-ubuntu-9.10

dont forget open the ports in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't have much time to put together a cleaner "how to". I just copied and pasted from my personal archive.

Here's what you'd have to do to compile the source code on a Compute Engine. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Image: debian-7-wheezy-v20140408

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.5.tar.gz
tar tar -xvzf yaml-0.1.5.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.1.5
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo apt-get install xsltproc
sudo apt-get install fop
cd ..
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B03-1.tar.gz
gunzip -c otp_src_R16B03-1.tar.gz | tar -xf -
cd o....
./configure --with-odbc=/usr/lib/odbc
sudo make
sudo make install

[.. Install git and clone repo here.. ]
git clone git@github.com:processone/ejabberd.git

cd ejabberd
./configure --enable-odbc --enable-mysql
sudo make
sudo make install
```